# NServiceBus Queue Per Tenant

Tags: nservicebus

I have a multi-tenant web app in which messages are sent to an NServiceBus endpoint using MSMQ.

The problem I have is that sometimes one tenant may execute a batch operation, and the endpoint gets bottle-necked by messages from this one tenant.  Subsequent messages from other tenants are then backed up in the message queue until the endpoint eventually gets to them.

What I would like to do is change the architecture so that I have a queue per Tenant.  On the sending side this code change would be simple...the bus.Send method can specify a queue name per tenant...and no changes are required to accommodate additional tenants that come on board.

But I don't know what change to make on the receiving side. As I understand NServiceBus Endpoint configurations, each endpoint can only listen to one incoming MSMQ queue.  Which tells me that I would have to have multiple instances of my endpoint-processing app...one for each tenant queue.  And this approach is not scalable - it requires dev-ops personnel to manually add a new instance with each new tenant sign-up.

1. Is there a way to achieve this with some kind of automation?
2. Is is there a way a single EndPoint-processing app can monitor multiple queues.
3. And if so (since we know the NSB configuration contains the logic to
   create a queue that does not exist at start-up) can it be used to
   create a new per-tenant queue after startup as each new tenant signs
   up?

I guess this is just a shout-out for advice from anyone who has run into a similar problem.

Comment: What about sending the batch operation messages to a separate endpoint instead?

Comment: Yeah that's an idea I didn't think of.  Thanks Udi.